# Using a range to limit the iterations of a list

Tags: python-2.7, list, range

Let's say I have a long list, and I only want to look at the first 10 items:

```
 l = ['werwerwer', 'erwerwer', 'ertertert', 'yuiyuiyui', 'qweqweqw'.......]
```

How can I use range to do that?

```
 for x in range (10):
     for item in l:
        while x < 10:
            print item
```

This just seems convoluted. What do I need to do here?

Comment: `for x in l[:10]:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the first 10 elements of a list like:

```
for x in l[:10]:
    print x
```

Comment: OK, that worked. I was trying to make it too complicated.